# How to use type/redis with redis?

Tags: typescript, redis, nestjs

Hi I am new at typescript and doing some demo projects using NestJs. I want to integrate redis. I was looking for some typescript friendly packages and found @type/redis [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/redis). But all it says is its a type definition of redis [github](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis). But I am not understanding how to use them together. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just install both packages: `npm install redis @types/redis` and use it in your project: `import redis = require('redis')`. Types hints should appear in TypeScript enabled editor.